# display/float, styling a list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm redoing a html table into a list.
It now looks like this:

```
<ul>

<li>Some fruits
<ul>
  <li>2013
    <ul>
      <li>Apple</li>
        <li>Kiwi</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</li>

<li>Some other fruits
<ul>
  <li>2012
    <ul>
      <li>Banana</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>2011
    <ul>
      <li>Lemon</li>
        <li>Orange</li>
        <li>Plum</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>2009
    <ul>
      <li>Peach</li>
      <li>Pear</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make the first entry in the sublist to align horizontally with the year. Like this:

```
2011   Lemon
       Orange
       Plum
```

The nested elements are doing my head in and I'm stuck. I have a feeling this will involve the display type of the elements and some floating. Any ideas? Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/HUH62/4/
Thanks.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're converting lists?  This looks like tabular data to me.

Comment: thought it would be easier to update, and it looks cleaner. there were lots of empty <td>s everywhere, for layout purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, here's the same fiddle modified according to what you are trying to accomplish: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HUH62/8/).

I added some classes in order to make the CSS more readable and wrapped the "subtitle" of each section in a div so that floatiing could be applied to them.

I also removed the colors, since I interpreted they were added only for visualizing the elements.

**CSS**

```
h4 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float:left;
}
ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li ul li ul {
    float:left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
ul li {
    clear:both;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>Some fruits
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h4>2013</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li>Apple</li>
                    <li>Kiwi</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Some other fruits
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h4>2012</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li>Banana</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h4>2011</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li>Lemon</li>
                    <li>Orange</li>
                    <li>Plum</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h4>2009</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li>Peach</li>
                    <li>Pear</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It seems more appropriate to use a heading element (h1, etc.) rather than a div to markup the year.

Comment: thanks, this works. but instead of adding divs and classes, would it be possible to arrive at the same results with something like `ul li ul li` etc?

Comment: @jimmy You could replace the `ul.subitems` with `ul li ul li ul`, but in order to have the year to the left of the subitems, you need an element to contain the text, in order to indicate that it floats.